# Make Windows 7 feel like Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, shortcuts, windows, scrolling

Are there any programs that can make my newly "BootCamped" Mac work like Lion (or at least Snow Leopard) when running Windows 7 Ultimate?

I'm talking about things like Command+L for the URL bar, (on Windows it locks the screen,) the Option key being used to navigate between words, inertial scrolling,  and, reverse scrolling.

I suppose the answer is probably no, but it's worth asking.

Comment: IMO, this is a **bad idea**, OS X and Windows do some things differently enough that it's probably worth the minor irritation of them doing things differently just so you don't accidentally do something expecting different behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of what you are looking for can be found in this Lifehacker article, "[How to Get Mac OS X’s Best Features on Windows](http://lifehacker.com/5807358/how-to-get-mac-os-xs-best-features-on-windows)".

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- Install Safari, QuickTime and iTunes and try them as replacements for
  IE and Windows Media Player. Control+L will work like Command+L to activate the URL bar.
- The Windows 7 Start Menu has a search feature pretty similar to Spotlight.
- You can use AutoHotKey or X-Mouse Button Control to invert the mouse scrolling to match Lion's.
- I actually made window management the same on both operating systems by installing [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) on OS X. That gives OS X the window snap features of Windows 7.

As I think of more tips I may include them here later, but those are the ones I remember out the top of my head. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After some poking around I could only find this: http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/08/make-your-windows-7-look-and-feel-like-a-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Yeah, it really isn't anything.

You may be able to custom configure your short cuts, but you may want to ask that on Superuser. (I don't know how to do that, but I have seen others do so)

Comment: After installing the Snow Transformation Pack my system became unstable and slow. For example, it took 5 minutes to shutdown.